# Why lookup in SortedDictionary<> is SLOWER than lookup in Dictionary<>?

Tags: .net, algorithm

As as human I always thought that lookup in something sorted is the way faster than lookup in not sorted.

But looking at this http://dotnetperls.com/sorteddictionary I can say that I was wrong.

Maybe anyone can explain why it is so ?

Comment: The article that you reference does a good job explaining this: "the SortedDictionary(TKey, TValue) generic class is a binary search tree with O(log n) retrieval, where n is the number of elements in the dictionary.". Did you have a more specific question or answer that you were looking for?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that. 
But then it's not logical, because most (all?) people thinks that lookup in smth sorted should be faster.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The unsorted dictionary is probably a hash map so lookup is almost O(1) assuming not too many collisions, while a lookup in a sorted list is best case O(log N)

Comment: Then I think naming of SortedDictionary<> should be changed to something else :). Because most people thinks (so do I) that lookup in something sorted should work definitely faster. I just made huge performance improvement to my algo, where lookup is very important... 
If I've knew this 3 moths ago, I would hear less screams, because of speed ;)

Comment: On the contrary, I would hope that any programmer would automatically think "O(log n)" when they hear "sorted".